# Why Authenticate Middleware not working for multi auth?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware

I want to have 3 guards for authentication:

1. Customer
2. Vendor
3. Admin

And they have to log in separately, also tables and models are separate.
All right, but the following code in authenticate middleware only works for admin!

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            if(Route::is('admin.*')){
                return route('admin.auth.login');
            }
            if(Route::is('vendor.*')){
                return route('vendor.auth.login');
            }
            return route('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Vendor routes are now redirected to the site index instead of login

Comment: When you do `dd(Request::route()->getName());`, what is the output on vendor versus on admin?

Comment: @AndrewGosselin For admin "null" & for vendor "vendor.index"

Comment: @AndrewGosselin Even if I clear the condition, admin still works correctly

Comment: If you change to Request::is('admin.*') or Route::current()->getName() == 'admin.*'  does it work?

Comment: @AlexandreBarbosa The condition works correctly and is true when I use dd()
Only problem with redirects

Comment: Right, I think another way would be changing the route name to the URI path, just for testing(For example suppose you have routes: admin/ and vendor/login): $request->is('admin/*'), $request->is('vendor/login/'). If ok, try again using $request->route('admin.*) and $request->route('vendor.auth.login') to get  the route that handles the request